# Working with two different set of colleagues on the same problem

Tags: publications, phd, authorship, collaboration

I am a Ph.D. student working on Computer Science. This is the situation. I thought of an interesting problem, and had a discussion about it with someone (call this person `A`) I wanted to establish a connection with. We discussed some ideas but they failed. We then stopped talking for a while.

Few weeks later I discuss this problem with another person, `B`, a postdoc at my group. We see no way of making progress in the first meeting. Then `B` tells me that `C`, a PhD student at my group, is also interested in the problem. We start having regular meetings the three of us (`B`, `C` and myself) and slowly make progress with the problem.

Then, after some months of silence, `A` contacts me proposing some early solutions to the problem that seem promising, clever and way more sophisticated than what `B`, `C` and I have been thinking of.

At this point I don't know how to proceed. Ideally, we could work on the problem the four of us, but it is unfair in light of the fact that the deepest contributions come from `A`, and the other three of us would be around just to help establishing the results and presenting them (`A` is an expert in a different field so it does need the help of one of us to make their techniques relevant, but three of us is too much I think). On the one hand, I have held discussions with `B` and `C`, which have led to essentially zero progress, but they have been interested in the topic nevertheless. Leaving them to (re)join `A` also sounds a bit inappropriate.

Any suggestion or advice is more than welcome. I can help clarifying the situation even more if you feel it's needed.

Comment: How theoretical/close to being mathematics is the area this problem is in?

Comment: @AlexanderWoo I don't think I understand the question completely, but maybe I can describe it as a problem within computer science that can be solved with techniques from mathematics. I can see the techniques `A` presents will likely solve it but there are many holes that must be filled in to make a full-fledged solution.

Comment: Yes, that's the price of talking to multiple people. Albeit at SE it is often suggested to talk to many people etc., it tends to be forgotten that once people have a stake in a problem, their entanglement is not easily reversed. The easiest, if people agree, is to merge the groups, but I can imagine resistance from A, and probably even more from B & C. So, you really need to be prepared for the case when the merge fails. I have no good suggestion for this situation at its current stage of progress. If A is most senior, maybe you can ask them for advice. But that depends on A. Very difficult.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Yes, it's rather complicated. `A` is senior so I trust this person will have an idea about how to proceed.

Comment: Recommend that you wait more than an hour to pick the selected answer. At least a day may be a good idea (allow everyone onsite a chance to see it in their daily schedule).

Comment: It's often recommended to use fake names instead of just letters, since we are used to reading names, like Alan, Betty, Charles.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Actually, you should let A know that you and the others have been working on the problem and propose that you merge into one group. If B and C haven't been productive on it, then you might want to discuss it with them first. It might be that one or both of them isn't ready for a more intensive collaboration.

You can, jointly, be honest with A that your progress has been slow.

But it would be a mistake to arbitrarily exclude anyone.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I also think it is completely inappropriate to simply split groups. I will talk to `A` tomorrow and expose the whole situation. `A` is rather senior so I'm sure this person will know how to proceed. Thanks for the answer